# annotate gem is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, annotate

I am using ruby 2.5.1, rails 5.2.0rc2 and annotate 2.7.2. However, when I run `rails db:migrate` annotate gem throws an error:

```
Unable to annotate app/models/a.rb: can't modify frozen String
Unable to annotate app/models/a.rb: no implicit conversion of nil into Array
Unable to annotate app/models/b.rb: can't modify frozen String
Unable to annotate app/models/b.rb: no implicit conversion of nil into Array
Unable to annotate app/models/c.rb: can't modify frozen String
Unable to annotate app/models/c.rb: no implicit conversion of nil into Array
```

I have found that setting `'show_indexes' => 'false'`, annotated the model but I also need to see Indices too.

Is there a fix for that?

Comment: I think there is some issue with rails 5 https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models/issues/538

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue.

Have updated to annotate 2.7.4 and it's working again.